# Does Apache Tika do character set conversion?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, apache-tika

I'm using `org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString()` to convert documents into plain text (i.e., unformatted text) files. My application potentially needs to convert documents that don't use a Unicode character set. For instance, some documents may be encoded in the `Chinese GB2312` character set. It would be great if Tika re-coded the output into `UTF-8`. This would require Tika to reference a mapping between many different character sets and Unicode in order to convert the characters.

Does Tika convert the non-Unicode character set text into Unicode as the output of `parseToString()`? There are a lot of character sets out there so I would be impressed if Tika did this for more than a few character sets.

Update: I was able to create a couple different files with some non-Latin charsets (GB2312 (Chinese) and KOI8-R (Russian)). `Tika.parseToString()` couldn't even detect the charset or encoding. I opened an issue on the Tika bug tracker here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1262

Comment: What kind of files would this be for? Plain text? HTML? PDF? Word? etc

Comment: Any sort of files. PDF and Word are good examples.

Comment: Nothing special there then. Tika gives you a Java String, which is Unicode, and anything character set related is entirely at your end when you turn that Unicode string back into bytes to output

Comment: @Gagravarr So what should Tika do when given a file that is not Unicode? It has to know the charset first before it can even try to parse it. The return value of parseToString() is a string. Java String is always encoded as UTF-16. If it knows the charset isn't Unicode it wouldn't make sense to encode the result with a Unicode UTF-16 encoding unless it converted it to Unicode first.

Comment: Gagravarr's comment gave me the idea to try using Tika.parse() instead of Tika.parseToString(). It still fails for every non-Latin character set I throw it. I'll give the Tika team a week or so to respond to the issue I submitted and then post my answer here.

Comment: Is the file plain text or binary? If it's binary, then the file format has its own way of storing encoding, and the libraries Tika uses handle that. If it's plain text, then Tika has code to detect encodings. Plain Text and Binary File formats are very different, so which one is it you're interested in?

Comment: The files I am trying are actually just Plain Text files but they don't use ASCII or UTF-* encodings. For instance the Russian file uses KOI9-R charset and encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When talking about Character Sets in Apache Tika, you need to consider two kinds of files differently. One kind is that of basically just plain text, the other are more complex types (including binary ones)

With the more complex files, Tika mostly uses third party libraries, and these libraries are responsible for returning Java Strings. The exact way of doing that will depend on the file format in question - sometimes the file format will including encoding information, other times it'll be fixed in what it supports. Either way, Tika gets Java Strings, and returns to you a Java String. How you choose to encode that for output is up to you. (For Windows users especially, check the encoding of your terminal, and the font used. There've been lots of "Tika Encoding Problems" which were actually people failing to correctly set the default Java encoding on output, or failing to have a Unicode capable terminal!)

With plain text files, there's no encoding information in the file, all we have is a bunch of bytes. Here, Apache Tika uses one of a number of [EncodingDetector](http://tika.apache.org/1.5/api/org/apache/tika/detect/EncodingDetector.html) instances to do the detection. These use hints, n-grams, language detection etc, to try to work out the most likely encoding of the file based on information given, pattern of bytes in the file etc.

The definition of EncodingDetector is held in the Tika-Core jar, but most of the implentations are held in the Tika-Parsers jar (and loaded by the service loader method, just like Detectors and Parsers). The main ones are [here in SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/txt). If you check there, you'll see the main list of encodings that Tika can detect.

One final thing - the encoding detection is only performed on files that are text files, it isn't done on the binary type files. Depending on how you call Tika, you might need to tweak that and/or provide a hint that it's a text file, so that the EncodingDetector logic gets triggered.

Answer (score 1):

This answer actually comes from a JIRA user on the Tika project. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1262

It turns out that if you tell Tika that the file extension is '.txt' it will treat the file as plain text, attempt to detect the encoding, and convert it to UTF.

An easy way to do this is to pass an empty Metadata object to *TikaInputStream.get()*. This will fill out the *resourceName* field of the Metadata object. Then pass this object to *parseToString()*. With the *resourceName* field set to a file name that ends with .txt the parser knows to treat this file as plain text and will do a encoding detection to try to discover how to decode the file. The string returned from *parseToString()* is a Java UTF-16  *String* object. When written to a file you can see that it is Unicode and uses the UCS charset.

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
TikaInputStream reader = TikaInputStream.get(new File(filepath), metadata);
String contents = tika.parseToString(reader, metadata);
```

So far this has worked for text files using either GB2312/GB18030 and KOI8-R. This is the expected behavior and it's perfect! I don't know what other charsets/encoding is can handle.